# Start karma tests in Firefox without privacy notice tab and disable extensions

Tags: firefox, karma-runner

I am using the `karma-firefox-launcher` plugin to launch my karama tests in Firefox, which works just fine. However every time it launches, Firefox seems to think this is a first-run and it also opens tabs for the [privacy notice](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/privacy/firefox/) page, and another one for an extension.

This is what I see every time I run the tests

[image: firefox tabs]

I was able to make a [custom launcher](http://karma-runner.github.io/4.0/config/browsers.html) for Firefox in my karma config file to start it in safe mode, like this:

```
customLaunchers: {
    firefox_custom: {
        base: 'Firefox',
        flags: ["-safe-mode"]
    },
},
```

Which works, but now it shows this dialog every time (which requires the button to be clicked to continue) and is is equally annoying

[image: firefox safe mode dialog]

In my attempt to disable the privacy notice tab, I've tried setting these preferences, but none have worked.  Perhaps I'm not setting them correctly?

`flags: ["-pref='app.normandy.first_run=false'"]`

and

`flags: ["-pref='datareporting.policy.firstRunURL='"]`

---

What CLI flags can I set here to **both** disable extensions without the additional dialog, **and** stop the privacy

Comment: opened an issue: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-firefox-launcher/issues/92

Answer (score 1):

According to [the `karma-firefox-launcher` docs](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-firefox-launcher#custom-preferences), you can set preferences directly, so after browsing around in the firefox `about:config` page and searching for "firstrun" I found a preference named `toolkit.telemetry.reportingpolicy.firstRun`

So, the following will work to prevent that privacy notice tab from opening, but the Adobe Acrobat extension "welcome" tab still opens.

```
firefox_custom: {
    base: 'Firefox',
    prefs: {
        'toolkit.telemetry.reportingpolicy.firstRun': false,
    }
},
```

It's improved but not all the way there yet!  I'll update this answer if I find anything else out.